# Python rpyc run in background

Tags: python, rpyc

I am using rpyc to create a Service (server). I was able to do this. Now I'm I would like to run it and connect to it using my client.
I run the  server

```
python3 myserver.py
```

This runs fine. Then I run the client

```
python3 myclient.py
```

The problem is I get an error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

When I run myserver.py from Anaconda Spyder, them my client works fine, but when I run my server from the shell or command prompt, it says connection refused. Is there a specific way I need to run a rpyc server in order to connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

First, check your firewall - is it open for RPyC server port
Also make sure your server uses for binding address 0.0.0.0 and not localhost (127.0.0.1)
Very important to ensure that both server and client use the same Python and RPyC versions